# Tkinter not updating in Windows OS when scrolling too fast

Tags: windows, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

[image: Fields Not Showing]

As seen in the example above, a mixture of the Label objects on the left column or Entry objects on the right column are not shown when scrolling too fast.

If I click on the scrollbar and drag quickly it can look as bad as this.  If I use the wheel on the mouse to scroll slowly it is **typically** fine, though sometimes a line will get missed no matter how slowly I scroll.  For reference, it seems to always be the same line(s) that do not show when scrolling slowly.

Changing tabs back and forth causes everything to draw properly again.  On Linux, everything works perfectly.  But this needs to work on Windows as well.

Not sure if it matters, but each line is a Label and Entry inside of a Frame inside of a Canvas that, along with a Scrollbar, is inside of a Frame.  Each of those top Frames is a "page" in a Notebook to provide the tabs shown on top.

**And finally some questions**.  Is there a button I can add to force this to redraw without destroying and recreating it?  Or possibly something I can add when creating these objects to force them to redraw when moved?

Sample code upon request:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

class WriteableEntry(Label):
    def __init__(self, name, value, *args, **kwargs):
        #~ self.ip = ip
        #~ self.ping_results = []
        super(WriteableEntry, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.label = name
        self.init_value = value
        self.written_value = ''

        self.field_name = Label(self, justify="left", text=name, width=25)
        self.field_value = Entry(self, justify='left', width=60)
        self.field_value.insert(END, value)
        self.field_name.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.field_value.pack(side=LEFT)


class InfoFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InfoFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.nb_frame = Frame(self, height=300, width=730)
        self.nb_frame.pack_propagate(False)
        self.nb = ttk.Notebook(self.nb_frame)
        self.nb.pressed_index = None

        filler = {}
        for x in range(0, 3):
            for y in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'):
                filler.update({"out%d_%s" % (x, y):"nada"})
        self.example_dict = {'A':filler, 'B':filler, 'C':filler}

        print("E_D:\n", self.example_dict)

        for page in sorted(self.example_dict):
            print("page:\t", page)
            entry_count = len(self.example_dict[page])
            #   #   ## Make new_page to put in nb
            new_page = Frame(self.nb)
            new_page.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
            #   #   ## Make canvas to put in that new_page
            canvas = Canvas(new_page)
            scroll = Scrollbar(new_page, command=canvas.yview)
            ## Orig *27
            canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set, scrollregion=(0,120,120,entry_count * 35))
            canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
            scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
            #   #   ## Make a frame to put in that canvas
            canvas_frame = Frame(canvas, bg='white', width=50, height=50)
            ## Orig +12 *10
            canvas.create_window(345, (entry_count + 12) * 13, window=canvas_frame)
            for value in sorted(self.example_dict[page]):
                print("value:\t", value)
                writeable_entry = WriteableEntry(value, self.example_dict[page][value], master=canvas_frame)
                writeable_entry.pack(side=TOP)

            self.nb.add(new_page, text=page)
        self.nb.pack(side=TOP, expand=True, fill="both")

        self.nb_frame.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)


class IPLabel(LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IPLabel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.info_frame = InfoFrame(master=self)
        self.info_frame.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky=E + W)


class AvailableApplication(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(AvailableApplication, self).__init__(master)
        #~ self.ips = ips
        self.grid()
        self.grid_propagate(True)
        self.ip_widgets = []
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.ip_frame = Frame(self)
        self.ip_widgets = []
        ip_widget = IPLabel(master=self.ip_frame)
        ip_widget.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=E + W)
        self.ip_widgets.append(ip_widget)
        self.ip_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=8)
        self.ip_frame.grid_propagate(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Example Script")
    app = AvailableApplication(root)
    app.mainloop()
    root.destroy()
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Sure thing.  I removed a majority of the code, but it is still a bit long.

Comment: What Bryan is asking from you is an example with the minimum that is needed to reproduce the problem. We don't need your original code. Things like `title()`, comments, other formatting code, print statements, are all basically useless to the problem. We need a simple tk window with the main widget that has the problem, the scrollbar, and maybe a loop that makes the content of that widget. That is all.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the `WriteableEntry`. It is not a `tk.Label`. You can't have sub widgets (a `tk.Label` and a `tk.Entry`) of a `tk.Label`. You also have the wrong layout manager for this work. Maybe also because of the wrong sub widget use. You rely on the wrap behavior of the `pack` manager. Don't. Use the `grid()` manager.

For some reason tab `C` is not visible but that is another problem.
Using `Ctrl-Tab` I found that there is a third tab but the tab text was the empty string. Adding the tab with

```
self.nb.add(new_page, text="P"+page)
```

Made it better visible. I have no idea why the tab name **"C"** has a special meaning for tkinter

The only possible way to kill the App and window is by using the `Close` button. So why do you destroy the root window? It is already destroyed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

class WriteableEntry(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value, *args, **kwargs):
        #~ self.ip = ip
        #~ self.ping_results = []
        #super(WriteableEntry, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        master = kwargs['master']
        row = kwargs['row']
        self.label = name
        self.init_value = value
        self.written_value = ''

        self.field_name = Label(master, justify="left", text=name, width=25)
        self.field_value = Entry(master, justify='left', width=60)
        self.field_value.insert(END, value)
        self.field_name.grid(row=row, column=0)
        self.field_value.grid(row=row, column=1)


class InfoFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InfoFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.nb_frame = Frame(self, height=300, width=730)
        self.nb_frame.pack_propagate(False)
        self.nb = ttk.Notebook(self.nb_frame)
        self.nb.pressed_index = None

        filler = {}
        for x in range(0, 3):
            for y in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'):
                filler.update({"out%d_%s" % (x, y):"nada"})
        self.example_dict = {'A':filler, 'B':filler, 'C':filler}

        print("E_D:\n", self.example_dict)

        for page in sorted(self.example_dict):
            print("page:\t", page)
            entry_count = len(self.example_dict[page])
            #   #   ## Make new_page to put in nb
            new_page = Frame(self.nb)
            new_page.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
            #   #   ## Make canvas to put in that new_page
            canvas = Canvas(new_page)
            scroll = Scrollbar(new_page, command=canvas.yview)
            ## Orig *27
            canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set, scrollregion=(0,120,120,entry_count * 35))
            canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
            scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
            #   #   ## Make a frame to put in that canvas
            canvas_frame = Frame(canvas, bg='white', width=50, height=50)
            ## Orig +12 *10
            canvas.create_window(345, (entry_count + 12) * 13, window=canvas_frame)
            for row, value in enumerate(sorted(self.example_dict[page])):
                print("value:\t", value)
                writeable_entry = WriteableEntry(value, self.example_dict[page][value], master=canvas_frame, row=row)
                #writeable_entry.pack(side=TOP)

            self.nb.add(new_page, text="P"+page)
        self.nb.pack(side=TOP, expand=True, fill="both")

        self.nb_frame.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)


class IPLabel(LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IPLabel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.info_frame = InfoFrame(master=self)
        self.info_frame.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky=E + W)


class AvailableApplication(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(AvailableApplication, self).__init__(master)
        #~ self.ips = ips
        self.grid()
        self.grid_propagate(True)
        self.ip_widgets = []
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.ip_frame = Frame(self)
        self.ip_widgets = []
        ip_widget = IPLabel(master=self.ip_frame)
        ip_widget.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=E + W)
        self.ip_widgets.append(ip_widget)
        self.ip_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=8)
        self.ip_frame.grid_propagate(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Example Script")
    app = AvailableApplication(root)
    app.mainloop()
    #root.destroy()
```